# trying to add an image as a pygame backgrounds

Tags: pygame

i have been trying to make my background of my maze game a picture that i have on my computer so that i can make the game look better. You can see my class for the background but i'm stuck and i'm not sure what to do, can anyone help it would be amazing.

```
import os
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
#Colours im using in the game
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

FPS = 60

#The dimension of the game
display_width = 680
display_height = 440

#Class for the player
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(40, 40, 30, 30)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        #Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        #Move the player
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        #If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: #Moving right, Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: #Moving left, Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: #Moving down, Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: #Moving up, Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

#Class for background
class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self) #call sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

#Class to hold a wall rect
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 40, 40)

#Initialise pygame
os.environ["Time to play"] = "1"

#Title of game
pygame.display.set_caption("Wrath of the gods")
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = [] #List to hold the walls
background = None
player = None
end_rect = None

def reinit():

    global player, end_rect

    player = Player() #Create the player

    #Holds the level layout in a list of strings.
    level = [   
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W    W    W     W",
    "W WW W WW   WWW W",
    "W W  W  W W W W W",
    "W WWWWW WWW W W W",
    "W  W  W   W   W W",
    "WW W WW WWWWWWW W",
    "W    W   W      W",
    "W WWWW W WWWWW WW",
    "W      W   W    W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWEW",
    ]

    # W = wall, E = exit
    x = y = 0
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                Wall((x, y))
            if col == "E":
                end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 40)
            x += 40
        y += 40
        x = 0

reinit()
bigfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
smallfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 45)

def play_again():

    SCREEN_WIDTH = display_width
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = display_height
    screen = gameDisplay
    text = bigfont.render("YOU WIN Play again?", 13, (0, 0, 0))
    textx = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2
    texty = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2
    textx_size = text.get_width()
    texty_size = text.get_height()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), ((textx - 5, texty - 5),
                                               (textx_size + 10, texty_size +
                                                10)))
    screen.blit(text, (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2,
                       SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))

    #Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.flip()
    in_main_menu = True
    while in_main_menu:

        clock.tick(50)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                in_main_menu = False
                return False

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                x, y = event.pos
                if x >= textx - 5 and x <= textx + textx_size + 5:
                    if y >= texty - 5 and y <= texty + texty_size + 5:
                        in_main_menu = False
                        return True

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False

    #Move the player
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(-2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -2)
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.move(0, 2)
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        again = play_again()
        if again:
            reinit()
        else:

            break

    #Draw the scene
    gameDisplay.fill((black))
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, end_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Is the background supposed to be moving or can it be stationary?

Comment: also, is it supposed to be a general background covering the whole screen  or a picture displayed in a certain location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm not sure why you want the background to be a sprite or a class, it seems an unnecessary implementation.

A background can be loaded using pygame.image.load() and stored as a surface and blitted making it easy to display.

A short example:

```
import pygame as py
py.init()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 360

screen = py.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))

background = py.image.load("image.png") ## Load the image file
background = py.transform.scale(background,(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT)) ## Make it the same size as the screen

clock = py.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.blit(background,(0,0)) ## Blit the background onto the screen first
    ## All other display stuff goes here
    py.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

py.quit()
```

If you need a sprite and/or class based method of displaying the background just ask, hope this helps.